# Send message button in facebook bot PAGE

Tags: php, facebook, curl

**good evening,**
I'm already breaking my head for 3 days I'm trying to send a message with the button from a page with a bot made in CURL PHP

I'm trying with CURL and PHP POST GRAPH
without success both of us can help me?

```
function SendRawResponse($Rawresponse){
    $userPageConversation = 't_100005050355547';
    $Access_token = "XXXX"; 
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/".$userPageConversation."/messages?access_token=".$Access_token;
    //$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=".$Access_token;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'charset=utf-8',
    );
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Rawresponse);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($Rawresponse));
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($Rawresponse)); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $erros = curl_errno($ch);
    $response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    var_dump($erros);
    var_dump($response);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

**Mensage:**

```
$teste = '{
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"button",
        "text":"Try the postback button!",
        "buttons":[
          {
            "type":"web_url",
            "title":"GOOGLE",
            "url":"https://www.google.com.br"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}}';
SendRawResponse($teste);
```

**erros:**

```
Warning: http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object. Incorrect value given

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($Rawresponse)); = Missing message body
```

Comment: You are passing a string to http_build_query. It expect an array or object.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($Rawresponse)); = Missing message body ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/url)
you must add domain to the whitelist in FB page settings.

Domains must meet the following [requirements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting) to be whitelisted:

- Served over HTTPS
- Use a fully qualified domain name, such as
  https://www.messenger.com/. IP addresses and localhost are not
  supported for whitelisting.